# why won't ButtonListener work?

Tags: java, swing, listener

So I am kind of trying to grasp the concept of Listeners and whatnot 
in my code I am getting the error:

```
The type eventHandle.ButtonListener must implement the inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)
```

Why is this happening?

```
package test;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class eventHandle extends JApplet{
    private JButton onebutton;
    private JButton twobutton;
    private JLabel label; 
    private int flax;
    private JPanel panel;

    public void init(){
        flax = 0;
        onebutton = new JButton("click to add 1");
        onebutton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        twobutton = new JButton("click to add 2");
        twobutton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        label = new JLabel("count: " + flax);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        panel.add(onebutton);
        panel.add(twobutton);

        Container contain = getContentPane();
        contain.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        contain.add(label);
        contain.add(panel);

        setSize(400,300);

    }
    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(Action event){
            if (event == onebutton){
                flax += 1;
            }
            if (event == twobutton){
                flax += 2;
            }
            label.setText("count: " + flax);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It needs to implement `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)`. You implemented `actionPerformed(Action)`.

Comment: @resueman: Sorry, I was writing my answer and I did not see your comment, I will up-vote your comment

Comment: [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are not overriding well the ActionListener interface, you have to do

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
```

instead of

```
public void actionPerformed(Action event){
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ActionEvent` instead of `Action` and to compare `JButton` object use `event.getSource()`.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
   if (event.getSource() == onebutton){
      flax += 1;
   }
   if (event.getSource() == twobutton){
     flax += 2;
   }
   label.setText("count: " + flax);
}
```

More https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html